# How to bind dynamically generated element to Intersection Observer?

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

This is the code that I'm using:

```
var ob = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    for(var entry of entries){
        console.log('works');
    }
});

document.querySelectorAll('dynamicElement').forEach(elem => ob.observe(elem));
```

This is working for elements that are on the page, but it doesn't work for elements that get dynamically created later. 
How do I bind an element that's inserted in the page later ?

I know with jquery you can bind it like `$(document).on('event', 'element', 'func');`, but how do I do it with the observer ?

Comment: Just the same. Buy you have to `observe` them after you create them.

Comment: @ritaj But how do i check for when the element is created ?

Comment: Well, where are you creating those elements?

Comment: @ritaj They are generated on click (so it appears) that's the problem I don't have access to that code

Comment: You have to give more info, but you definitely have to find some event upon dynamicElement creation and add newly found elements to observer.

Comment: @ritaj While on facebook, on the chat box, if you click an image it goes full screen and it lazy-loads, I'm trying to intercept when the image I clicked on has loaded so I can dowloand it.

Comment: You could do some sort of `setInterval` which will check when the image has loaded and reapply observer, I guess.

Comment: @ritaj Yup, that was my first approach, but when downloading multiple pictures it gets kida messy, that's why i needed a more reliable way.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but basically I had the same problem recently and did not find any answer on the net so after investigating the obvious solution was to use the MutationObserver() API together with IntersectionObserver().

Basically you choose a non-dynamic parent of the dynamically generated children elements and attach a mutationObserver to its childList.

Subsequently on mutation detected (on the mutation observer callback) you select the dynamically generated element and attach the intersection observer to it.

Additionally if you use a querySelectorAll you can also use a forEach to attach an intersection observer to all the dynamic elements you wish as you were suggesting on your question.

Something like:

```
// Mutation Observer
   
const mSection = chatSection.querySelector(".non-dynamic-parent"),
    mObsOptions = {
      childList: true,
    },
    mObserver = new MutationObserver(mObs_CB);

  function mObs_CB(mutations) {
    for (let mutation of mutations) {
      if (mutation.type === "childList") {
        console.log("Mutation Detected");        

        //Start the Intersection Observer Here
        const intObsAllElem = document.querySelectorAll(".dynamicElement");        
        intObsAllElem.forEach(function (elem) {
          intObserver.observe(elem);
        });
      }
    }
  }

  mObserver.observe(mSection, mObsOptions);

 
//Intersection Observer
  
   const intObsOptions = {
         root: null,
         threshold: 1,
         rootMargin: "0px",
    },
    intObserver = new IntersectionObserver(intObs_CB, intObsOptions);

  function intObs_CB(entries, observer) {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
         if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            console.log("intersecting");
         } else {
            console.log("not intersecting");
         }

      });

  }
```

Comment: This is the same basic approach I use. I think what I've got may be a bit simpler, but anyway. Your code could do with some formatting, by the way :). Could garner an upvote from me, maybe after a little simplification of the structure and improvements in naming...

Comment: Thanks, I am actually Electronics Engineer, not programmer, so this is the best I could come up with. For me it is like an achievement given that the answer was not found anywhere else and that I usually come to stack overflow for questions, not answers.

Comment: This is really slow...