# Intersection observer not working on elements added through JS

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I made a car dealership page. I store data about cars in an array of objects, then I loop through it to insert data into my HTML file to display on a page. It works fine.

The problem arises when I try to add a lazy load function using intersection observers. The stuff gets put into page correctly but the intersection observer doesn't see the images and doesn't load them.

Here is a link to a codepen https://codepen.io/russiandobby/pen/xxxJvxv?editors=0010 , if you change `data-src` to `src` it will work.

How can I make it work so I can have lazy-loading.

```
 <img data-src="${car.img}" alt="jag1" class="card-img-top car-img popup-img">
```

Comment: I provided an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52217333/how-to-bind-dynamically-generated-element-to-intersection-observer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main code is fine.

The only issue is that it runs at the wrong time. While you DOM generation code runs on `DOMContentLoaded`, you try to attach the observer right away, so no images are in the DOM yet.

You will need to put your observer code inside the `DOMContentLoaded` as well, or create a method and call it from there.

Updated code: https://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/XWWBvQm?editors=0010

(*your codepen would also fail because you use a jquery plugin without including the jQuery library*)

Comment: Thx didnt realize i was making such a mistake T_T